# PdfView inside Listview is showing error?

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview

I am trying to put a PdfView and a close button inside a ListView.  But it throws the following error

> Exception caught by rendering library
> The following assertion was thrown
> during performLayout():
> _PlatformViewPlaceholderBox object was given an infinite size during layout.
>
> This probably means that it is a render object that tries to be as big
> as possible, but it was put inside another render object that allows
> its children to pick their own size.

Below is my code . I also tried giving it inside a Column under SingleChildScrollView. Still same error.

```
 ListView(children: [
              PDFView(
                filePath: pFile.path,
              ),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                child: IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.close,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ]),
```

What is missing here ? Can someone help ?

Comment: assign specific height for PDFView

Comment: @MunsifAli That  trims the content too..

Comment: why are you placing it inside ListView?

Comment: To show a close button at the top

Comment: you show it without ListVIew. place that button in appbar.

Comment: or bottom navigationbar. another solution is to use bottomsheet property of scaffold

Comment: @DroidBee You can also use Stack or Column to show the button at top.

Comment: Okay . I think I ll better place it in the app bar.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've wrapped the list view with the sizedBox and assigned a specific height and width, or else wrapped the PDFView with the specific height and width, it may work because the main issue is regarding the space that it's not allotted to that particular widget, so he cant take its own size.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**Remove Listview and use Column with Expanded widget**

```
Column(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: PDFView(
        filePath: pFile.path,
      ),
    ),
    Align(
      alignment: Alignment.topRight,
      child: IconButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
        },
        icon: const Icon(
          Icons.close,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```